# Motion.AI bot with Smooch doesnt work in Telegram group conversation

Tags: telegram, chatbot, smooch, supportkit

I have created a bot in Motion.AI and integrated it with telegram bot through Smooch.
When telegram user talks to bot directly, everything works fine. But when i try the group conversaiton in Telegram (created a Group in Telegram with 2 users and a bot), the bot does not work.

Does anybody know the reason? Is the issue on Smooch side?

Thank you in advance,
Levon

Answer (score 1):

Group conversations are not currently supported by Smooch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea when i will be supported?